# Android - gradle testProguardFile - what is its purpose relating to unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

Can someone help me understand the use of testProguardFile. Lets say i have  debug buildType and its configured like this in gradle build file:

```
// inside android block
    debug {
        shrinkResources true  // removes unused graphics etc
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testProguardFile('test-proguard-rules.pro')
    }
```

then why am i supplying another proguard rules file called test-proguard-rules.pro for testing ? If i understand correctly, when i do instrumentation testing a separate apk is generated but what if i'm doing just unit test, is it also the case ?

what i would like to be able to do is run "unit tests" (not instrumentation tests) but have the unit test apk use the proguard rules that i have defined in my project build settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now i see what it is testProguadFile ('some proguard file') gives your test apk a proguard file to use when testing.  This allows us test our app using a proguard file. The test apk generated when you run a test will be obfuscated with proguard and then the test will run.  This is a good way to test for any anomalies proguard could create in your app.

Comment: does those rules are for the test method of the apk, or the whole apk. I means does test-rules should include debug-rules ?

Comment: @Anthony testProguardFile is only for the test apk, the one that gets created as app/build/outputs/apk/app-dev-debug-androidTest.apk which calls methods from your regular apk.  The test rules do not need to include the regular debug rules.

Answer (score 11):

As I try to explain in my blog post - [Configuring ProGuard for Android Instrumentation Tests](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/configuring-proguard-for-android-instrumentation-tests-120d58cba155):

Initially, there are **roughly** 2 main, *distinct* Gradle tasks for running instrumentation tests: `assembleRelease` and `assembleAndroidTest`. The former executes what's needed in order to generate the app `.apk`. The latter triggers the assembly of an instrumentation testing `.apk`, which gets installed on the test device alongside the app when instrumentation tests are run (both are run in the context of the same OS process).

While `proguardFiles` sets the list of ProGuard rule files to consider when generating the app `.apk`, **`testProguardFiles`** does the same with respect to the instrumentation `.apk`.

So, while the naming is confusing, `testProguardFiles` has no effect on *unit* tests, but it's important for instrumentation tests running in ProGuard-enabled projects.