# Uncaught translation error Build proguard

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-build, android-proguard

I am facing this error when I try to build my project using `Android Studio` with `minifyEnabled true`.

Error's details

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: expected type int but found com.apptimize.hz
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: expected type int but found com.apptimize.oa
2 errors; aborting
```

**How can I resolve it?**

**UPDATE***

Proguard file's content.

> -optimizationpasses 5
>   -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
>   -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
>   -dontpreverify
>   -verbose
>   -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
>
> -dontwarn android.support.**
>   -dontwarn com.atinternet.**
>   -dontwarn org.apache.**
>
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
>   -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
>   -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
>
> -keepattributes InnerClasses
>   -keepattributes *Annotation*
>   -keepattributes Signature
>
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>       native ; }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>       public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>       public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); }
>
> -keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {    public void *(android.view.View); }
>
> -keepclassmembers enum * {
>       public static **[] values();
>       public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String); }
>
> -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *; }
>
> -dontwarn java.awt.**
>   -dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
>   -keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
>
> -keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
>   -dontwarn uk.co.senab.photoview.**
>   -keep class uk.co.senab.photoview.** { *; }

I used `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'`

**Is there any problem with my proguard file?**

Comment: Did you configure ProGuard to properly work with aaptimize? See http://apptimize.com/docs/installation/android-install/

Comment: I never use aaptimize before.

Comment: you should post your proguard config here

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc i updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

See plowman's answer at [Compile with Proguard gives SimException: "local variable type mismatch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701126/compile-with-proguard-gives-exception-local-variable-type-mismatch)

Add this to disable a specific optimization that triggers the proguard bug.

-optimizations !code/allocation/variable

worked for me.

Comment: Well didn't help me. Getting this `AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: type mismatch: expected array type but encountered java.lang.Object","sources":[{}]}`.
God only knows what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue after 3 to 4 days of detailed exploring .Problem arise in gradle version and way of handling dex and classes .

Fix for this can

There are two kind of cases

**Case 1 :** Since android test cases lots of complication with Mock and Instrumentation test cases.For test cases to pass we have to disable **minifyEnabled false** which disable progaurd process **testCoverageEnabled false**  .If enbale testCoverageEnabled true which cause this issue .For test cases should be passed the you have to disable progaurd in debug mode and testCoverageEnable false .

```
  debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled false
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Case 2: Define testProgurdFile and make minifyEnabled true  to proguard in debug mode as wel.

[Compile with Proguard gives SimException: "local variable type mismatch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701126/compile-with-proguard-gives-exception-local-variable-type-mismatch) define testProgurdFile as done on below Which will be used for testing in which you can specify the testing progaurd rules one which consumed by testFramework.

```
 debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testProguardFiles 'test-proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Reference links :

- [proguard gradle debug build but not the tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463089/proguard-gradle-debug-build-but-not-the-tests)
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159831
- [Android - gradle testProguardFile - what is its purpose relating to unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988579/android-gradle-testproguardfile-what-is-its-purpose-relating-to-unit-tests)
- [What are list of tasks thats ConnectedAndroidTest executes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713525/what-are-list-of-tasks-thats-connectedandroidtest-executes)